# Cómo filtrar por campos y contar registros mediante sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Imaginemos que tengo un fichero csv con las variables (columnas) Nombre y Trabajo, tal que:

```
Pedro   Ingeniero
Juan    Electricista
Antonio Electricista
Jose    Arquitecto
Roberto Ingeniero
```

¿Habría alguna manera de utilizar `sed` para poder ver el campo Trabajo y el número de observaciones que tiene cada uno o no es posible? Es que estoy buscando por internet como filtrar por campos y contar los registros mediante `sed` pero por ahora no he tenido mucho éxito en mi búsqueda.

Siguiendo con el ejemplo, la salida deseada sería:

```
Ingeniero 2,
Electricista 2,
Arquitecto 1.
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed es una herramienta para parsear *streams* (no en vano, es *stream editor*, s-ed). Para procesar datos y operar con ellos es mejor hacer combinación con `sort` y demás, como hiciste. O bien usar algo más complejo como Awk, Perl o vete a saber qué.

En este caso, Awk nos lo hace de una forma bastante elegante:

```
awk '{contador[$2]++} END{for(item in contador) print item, contador[item]}' fichero
```

Donde:

- `{contador[$2]++}`
  Define un array `contador[]` cuyos índices son la 2.ª columna de tu fichero. Cada vez que hay un elemento tipo "Ingeniero", "Electricista" o demás, el array suma uno a `contador[Ingeniero]`, de modo que finalmente acaba teniendo valores del tipo `contador[Ingeniero]=2`, `contador[Arquitecto]=1` y demás.
- `END{for(item in contador) print item, contador[item]}`
  Una vez ha terminado de recorrer el fichero, se ejecuta el bloque `END{}`. En él, iteramos sobre el contenido del array `contador[]` e imprimimos el valor de cada uno de los registros que hemos almacenado.

En tu caso, devuelve:

```
Electricista 2
Arquitecto 1
Ingeniero 2
```

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias por la aclaración fedorqui!

Answer (score 1):

Al final he visto que no se puede hacer lo que quiero utilizando explícitamente sed, así que lo que he hecho es borrar los espacios en blanco con sed y he utilizado cut, sort y uniq para contar las líneas que estaban repetidas:

`sed '/^$/d' fichero.csv | cut -d ',' -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`

Answer (score 1):

También puedes intentar con esto:

```
$ awk '$0=$2' profesiones | sort | uniq -c
```

El cual sólo aplica un truco sucio con `awk` donde el segundo campo se le convierte en todo registro. Luego la salida se ordena con `sort` y posteriormente se cuentan las ocurrencias con `uniq -c`.

Resultando en:

```
  1 Arquitecto
  2 Electricista
  2 Ingeniero
```

Ahora que, si de verdad amas `sed` con todo tu corazón, o es asunto de vida o muerte, puedes utilizar este script que adapté de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781329/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-using-sed):

```
#!/bin/sed -rnf

#  Descomenta y comenta según quieras saber las coincidencias de
#+ tal o cual profesión
/Electricista$/! be
#/Ingeniero$/! be
#/Arquitecto$/! be

x
/^$/ s/^.*$/0/
/^9*$/ s/^/0/
s/.9*$/x&/
h
s/^.*x//
y/0123456789/1234567890/
x
s/x.*$//
G
s/\n//
h

:e

$ {x;p}
```

Sólo guardalo en un archivo llamado *sed_script* (o como quieras), dale permisos de ejecución con `chmod u+x sed_script`.

Finalmente ejecutalo seguido del nombre de tu archivo:

```
$ ./sed_script profesiones # Tu archivo se llama "profesiones"
2
```

Como indican los comentarios en el script, comenta y descomenta según quieras tal o cual profesión.